# Character Encoding problem?

Tags: php, mysql, character-encoding

In my mysql database I have the following information in a page name field.

> ç,Ç,ö,Ö,ü,Ü,ı,İ,ş,Ş,ğ,Ğ

If I do a phpmyadmin dump the above is exported.

I am using a different php script and instead of the above I am getting this.

> "Ã§,Ã‡,Ã¶,Ã–,Ã¼,Ãœ,Ä±,Ä°,ÅŸ,Åž,ÄŸ,Äž"

This is the snippet which is generating the output.

```
$data_sql = "SELECT * FROM ".$table_name;
$data_res = @mysql_query($data_sql);


while($data_row = @mysql_fetch_array($data_res,MYSQL_NUM))
{
 print_r($data_row);
}
```

How can I modify this to make sure that the data is correct? Is some sort of php function required? Do I need to do something to the file?

Any advice is much appreciated.

Comment: What is your question exactly? What code do you use to connect to the database? What character set and collation does the table have that you are storing this in?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set client encoding this way:

```
mysql_connect();
mysql_select_db("database");
mysql_query("SET CHARACTER SET utf8");
```

Answer (score 0):

**[See this please. You need UTF8 format.](http://www.oreillynet.com/onlamp/blog/2006/01/turning_mysql_data_in_latin1_t.html)**

Answer (score 0):

No, this code doesn't change your symbols. you do it somewhere else

Edit: now, after your edit, it become clear that you haven't proper encoding set. SET NAMES should help