# PHP Turkish Language displaying issue

Tags: php

I have been trying to display my text in PHP but I am getting issue from Turkish characters it display it as Ä±Ä±Ä±Ã¶Ã¶Ã¶

I am reading data from MySQL but the issue is from the PHP. Please what it is missing?

My code is simple:

```
<?php

echo "ş i ü ğ";

?>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [UTF-8 all the way through](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/279170/utf-8-all-the-way-through)

Comment: save a file as UTF-8 encoding

Comment: Your file is probably saved as UTF-8, but your web page is probably being output in a single by encoding (e.g. ISO-8859-1). The best thing to do is probably to change the page's encoding to UTF-8 also.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Character Encoding problem?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2537740/character-encoding-problem)

Comment: As one of the TOP GUNS always mentions about this type of problem, your encoding must be done from `A to Z`, starting from the file's encoding format, right up to DB insertion/retrieval, mainly `UTF-8`.

Comment: @Pekka웃 I have tried it but it didn't work

Comment: @TamilSelvan How can I save it as UTF-8 ?

Comment: what editor you used?

Comment: @LuaiKalkatawi Get a copy of Notepad++ and you will have different methods to save in UTF-8. If all fails, then you may need to "Encode as UTF-8 without BOM". Visit the site => http://notepad-plus-plus.org/

Comment: The file likely already is UTF-8. Now add the proper headers to declare the page is UTF-8 and it should work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check, if your website is in UTF-8.

Just copy following code to the `<header>` tag of your `documment`:

```
<meta http-equiv='Content-Type' content='text/html; charset=utf-8'>
```

Or you can use just shorter version according to `HTML5`. [Compatibility is fine](http://code.google.com/p/doctype-mirror/wiki/MetaCharsetAttribute):

```
<meta charset='utf-8'>
```

See difference between this two `metatags`: [<meta charset="utf-8"> vs <meta http-equiv="Content-Type">](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4696499/meta-charset-utf-8-vs-meta-http-equiv-content-type)

Or you can use header. This code place into your `PHP code`. The best position is at the start of the `document`.

```
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
```

Or check if your file is in `UTF-8`.  This you can do with your code editor. I use [PSPad](http://www.pspad.com/en/) and i recommend it to try.

Comment: The `header(...)` should have immediate effect and give a correct result.

Comment: I have tried this before could you just explain to me where I am going to use it exactly? I don't know much about web service.

Comment: It works after I just added the header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');

Answer (score 2):

In addition to meta headers, the file's own character encoding is also important. I had suffered from the same issue with the files generated with notepad++ and notepad back in Windows, then I saved the file as UTF-8 and it all solved it.

E.g: with Sublime Text; file/save with encoding/UTF-8.

Comment: Notepad++ shouldn't "create" a problem, unlike Windows Notepad. Notepad++ has different encoding methods. I use Notepad++ with success all the time.

Comment: @Fred-ii- I don't know, I am the main translator of PHP-Fusion to Turkish, and Notepad++ made me suffer from that exactly issue a couple of years ago (I had to type ascii equivalents of all Turkish characters). I don't know about the current situation though.

Comment: One of the causes could be if saved with or without BOM. That has made a difference in a lot of cases for me. Someone should have thought about upcoming problems using characters as such, what a pain in the neck it is :( it's a constant battle.

Comment: You might consider trying out HAPedit 3.1 or Codelobster PHP Edition. I find that they have options that Notepad++ does not have.

Comment: @Fred-ii- I was using PHPDesigner after that chaos for a while, but I dropped Windows environment for development totally (and gladly personally!). As a current Linux User, Sublime Text is exactly suits my needs, Thanks though!:)